# How to load image for Android ImageView from classpath?

Tags: android

I have an Android App which contains an external dependend jar library. This external library contains some png-bitmaps which I want to show on some ImageViews in my application.

Looking inside the apk file of my application I can find the images in a sub directory ("aq\img") as expected.

What is the best way to show an image (insight the classpath) on a ImageView.

I tried this

```
    ImageView imgView01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath("aq/img/sample.png");
    imgView01.setImageDrawable(d);
```

and this

```
    InputStream is = ClassLoader
            .getSystemResourceAsStream("sample.png");
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    imgView01.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

but it did not work (I did not really expect it to be that simple).
The image remains empty.

Thanks for help!

Regards Klaus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PNG image is not a "system resource" because a system resource on Android is a file in the regular filesystem. The image that you want is within the APK archive. You would be able to use [`getSystemResourceAsStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to open an `InputStream` for reading the bytes of the APK archive, but not a file within the archive unless you implemented the logic to extract the file yourself.

Simply use this:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("aq/img/sample.png");
```

**EDIT:** Note that on Android, the name that is passed to `getSystemResourceAsStream` is treated as a path to the file relative to root (`/`). Because the APKs are stored in `/data/app`, then to open an `InputStream` for reading the APK, you can use `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("data/app/PACKAGE-1.apk")`, where "PACKAGE" is the package of your app.