# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file/path.jpg open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, arrays, inputstream, apache-commons, parse-platform

I am **trying** to save an image to [parse.com](https://parse.com/apps). I need to convert it to byte array. The way I have decided to try to do this is to use [apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). It is not quite working properly. This is my code snippet;

```
private void saveImage() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    InputStream header = new FileInputStream("/ClashMMA/res/drawable-hdpi/beatdown.jpg");

    ParseFile file = new ParseFile(toByteArray(header));
    try{
        file.save();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ParseObject displayImage = new ParseObject("displayImage");
    displayImage.put("header", file);
    try{
        displayImage.save();
    } catch (ParseException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private byte[] toByteArray(InputStream header) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int l;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((l = header.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
          buffer.write(data, 0, l);
        }
        buffer.flush();
        return buffer.toByteArray();

}
```

And my error is this;

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /ClashMMA/res/drawable-hdpi/beatdown.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

But I am sure that the file is there, because I went to my file directory (in eclipse), right clicked, and clicked on `Copy Qualified Name`. Which essentially copies the file path. I have tried a few other paths, Like right off of my computer, and in my `src` folder. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Why won't it read the file when in fact it is there? Detailed explanations please.

Comment: I had this problem. I deleted the folder created programmatically and created it manually and the problem solved!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files in your Eclipse projects are not in the (real or emulated) Android file system, and that is where the Android `FileInputStream` is looking.  (With good reason!  The host file system for Eclipse won't be there on a real Android device.)

You've basically got two choices:

- get them into the APK archive so that you can load them using `getSystemResourceAsStream`:  see [How to load image for Android ImageView from classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853695/how-to-load-image-for-android-imageview-from-classpath)
- copy the files into the Android file system so that `FileInputStream` can find them.

Comment: You may add every image you need on a resources folder.